Is U- shaped magnet natural or man-made?
I see in some web source that U- shaped magnet are available naturally also. The magnetic dipole moment is due the electrons spin direction and so if we cut the magnet the poles are created automatically. Being like that how is it possible for the atomic layout and so the electrons spin arrange or align naturally to have the poles side by side in U shaped magnet.

Which web sources?

https://byjus.com/question-answer/a-u-shaped-magnet-is-a-natural-magnet/

Is this valid? Found a couple of other sources while googling but not showing now in the google search for you to share.

what does "natural" mean in this context? Your link providws no explanation at all.

That byjus web site to which you linked claims to be "Your AI tutor." Need I say more?

The question is unclear, and the answer on the website doesn't make it more clear. I think there's not much to learn here, just the type of question that you move on from because it's not a great question. It makes me think that there are other better websites to learn from. Generally, U-shaped magnets are man-made. I don't know if there is something similar that can be found in nature, but if so, it's not supported by the answer given on the website.

Byju's must have gone crazy to write something like that. Natural magnets occur from the magnetic/mixed ore of iron ($Fe_3O_4$). I can assure you that if you even try your best, you will hardly find a bar shaped natural magnet. So, finding a horseshoe natural magnet (in nature) makes no sense.

The magnetic dipole moment is due the electrons spin direction and so if we cut the magnet the poles are created automatically. Being like that how is it possible for the atomic layout and so the electrons spin arrange or align naturally to have the poles side by side in U shaped magnet.

This has nothing to do with the fact of being able to find horseshoe magnets in nature or not.
Hope that helps.

Byju's is basically a bot so there's that.........

That information that Byju's is a bot is quite wrong. But why do you think so?

The search bar literally says “Find your solution with AI tutor.”

Oh! I get that but Byju's answers are not AI generated. It is only the search, which uses AI.

Oh ok then that makes sense I guess
